# How can I access the Mac Native Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

The application I'm using uploads a file with the Native Mac Dialog Box.  I can't seem to get Puppeteer to move around this box.  I have tried using process.on(dialog), page.keyboard.press & robotjs but none of those options seem to be able to access this dialog box. 
process.on is never triggered
page.keyboard doesn't do anything and I figure because the box is not on the page
robotjs.. I'm not sure why that isn't working either.

Does anyone have any other suggestions or working solutions I can try?

[image]

```
page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
    await robot.keyTap('tab');
    await robot.typeString(filename);
    await robot.keyTap('tab');
    await robot.keyTap('tab');
    await robot.keyTap('down');
    await robot.keyTap('enter');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. This dialog cannot be accessed from within puppeteer.

**Alternative Solution**

Instead of clicking on the button that opens the file dialog, you need to use [`elementHandle.uploadFile`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths) to place the file into the form:

```js
const fileInputField = await page.$('#SELECTOR-OF-FILE-INPUT');
await fileInputField.uploadFile('PATH/TO/YOUR.FILE');
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is not an input field but thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get around the dialog is by using the `dialog` argument. e.g.:

```js
page.on('dialog', dialog => {
    dialog.accept();
    //if it's a prompt
    dialog.accept('Foo');
    //or
    dialog.dismiss();
});
```